# Error returning an entity as json in controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TWPF.png)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/addassessment", method=  RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8",headers = "Accept=*/*")
@ResponseBody
public Assessment addAssessment(@RequestParam("creationDate") Date creationDate,
    @RequestParam("detail") String detail,
    @RequestParam("idCurrencyExchange") int idCurrencyExchange,
    @RequestParam("idSaClient") int idSaClient,
    @RequestParam("idStatus") int idStatus,
    @RequestParam("idUser") int idUser) {

try{
    Assessment assessment = new Assessment();
    assessment.setIdAssessment(0);
    assessment.setCreationDate(creationDate);
    assessment.setCurrencyExchange(currencyExchangeService.getCurrencyExchange(idCurrencyExchange));
    assessment.setDetail(detail);
    assessment.setSaClient(saClientService.findById(idSaClient));
    assessment.setStatus(statusServiceImpl.findById(idStatus));
    assessment.setUser(userService.findById(idUser));

    LOG.info(assessment.toString());
    assessment = assessmentService.addAssessment(assessment, idUser);
    return assessment;

}catch(Exception ex){
    return null;
}
```

This returns :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.unimer.cotizaciones.entities.Assessment["currencyExchange"]->com.unimer.cotizaciones.entities.CurrencyExchange["country"]->com.unimer.cotizaciones.entities.Country_$$_jvst5f1_21["handler"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1190) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:260) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:716) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:716) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:716) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:481) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:320) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr3.jar:2.9.0.pr3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:281) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:757) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.M1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]

    Hibernate: select user0_.id_user as id_user1_52_, user0_.account_bank as account_2_52_, user0_.commission_amount as commissi3_52_, user0_.confirmation_token as confirma4_52_, user0_.id_country as id_coun19_52_, user0_.creation_date as creation5_52_, user0_.credential_expired as credenti6_52_, user0_.credential_expired_at as credenti7_52_, user0_.email as email8_52_, user0_.expired as expired9_52_, user0_.expired_at as expired10_52_, user0_.last_loggin as last_lo11_52_, user0_.last_modification as last_mo12_52_, user0_.lastname as lastnam13_52_, user0_.midname as midname14_52_, user0_.name as name15_52_, user0_.password as passwor16_52_, user0_.id_rol as id_rol20_52_, user0_.status as status17_52_, user0_.use_commission as use_com18_52_ from user user0_ where user0_.email like ?
    Hibernate: select rol0_.id_rol as id_rol1_43_0_, rol0_.detail as detail2_43_0_, rol0_.status as status3_43_0_ from rol rol0_ where rol0_.id_rol=?
    Hibernate: insert into trace_response (action_user, detail, entry_date, ip, url) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    2017-06-15 13:06:21.229  INFO 5908 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] c.u.c.c.TraceResponseInterceptor         : URL to: 'http://localhost:8090/error' in '19' ms
```

Comment: 404 Question not found.

Answer (score 0):

One of your CurrencyExchange or User has lazy initialized attribut.

First option should be to fetch the lazy initialized data, but you maybe not need this data.

An other option is to create a data transfert object class :

```
public class UserDto {

  private Long id;

  // other attributs


  public UserDto(Long id, ...) {
    this.id = id;
    // ...
  }

}
```

Then you can retrieve the user with a new method :

```
findUserDto(Long id) {

  Query query = em.createQuery("select new UserDto(user.id, ...) from UserDto user where user.id = :userId");
  query.setParameter("userId",id);
  return query.getResultList();
}
```